# Hibernate Dialect for Apache Kylin

Tags: hadoop, olap, kylin

I want to try the Jpa Implementation for OLAP cube built by Apache Kylin.Is there any hibernate dialect i can use for Apache Kylin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know there is no hibernate dialect for Kylin. Kylin's SQL is a subset (only query) of ANSI-SQL. Most Kylin users are using tools like Tableau, Superset, or they developed their own query tool to send SQL to Kylin. Hibernate is widely used in the OLTP, I didn't see many cases in OLAP. Just my two cents.